# Proper definition of logical operation in Q.E.C

Tags: error-correction

My question is related to [this topic](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15301/transversal-logical-gate-for-stabilizer-or-at-least-steane-code)

I consider working with error correcting code on which I want to define logical operations.

Let's assume I want to define a logical operation on logical qubit. In the context of Stabilizer code we would have to make sure that this operation acts in the code space as explained [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15338/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-to-define-logical-operation-stabilizer-code/15340?noredirect=1#comment21216_15340).

But this is not enough, we must also verify that the logical gate, once ensured it preserves the code space does the **appropriate** operation.

### Some general requirements

I call $A$ the gate I want to implement logically under $A_L$. I call $C$ the code space.

One condition I must have is to ensure: $\forall |\psi \rangle \in C, A_L |\psi \rangle \in C$.
But this is not enough, I must "preserve" the action of this operation on the logical space.

One **necessary** condition would be to make sure that:

$$ \forall X: [A,X] \rightarrow [A_L,X_L]$$

I don't know how to phrase it precisely mathematically but basically it is to say that the commutator of $A$ with any other operator has the same "shape" as in the logical space.

And as $n$-Pauli matrices form a basis of $U(n)$, I guess this condition would by linearity be equivalent to say:

$$ \forall E \in G_n, [A,E] \rightarrow [A_L, E_L] $$

Where $G_n$ is the $n$-Pauli matrices group. But still: is ensuring commutation rule **enough** or is it only **necessary** to preserve the meaning of the operation ?

### My question in the end

What is a rigorous way to define logical operation on a quantum error correcting code. And if there are some "nice" equivalent way to define them I would be interested to know them. If we cannot be absolutely general, I will be fine with a definition for Stabilizer codes.