# Understanding transversal gates for the 7 qubit steane code

Tags: error-correction, universal-gates, fault-tolerance, clifford-group

How can one derive the complete list of transversal operators for the 7-qubit Steane code? I can derive the Clifford operators that are transversal, but I do not understand an easy way to check for non-Clifford transversal operators, and some idea on how to do this in general would be helpful. If there is a reference that would help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess a follow up question is that there do exist stabilizer codes with transversal none Clifford gates. How does one check for such a gate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Eastin-Knill theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastin%E2%80%93Knill_theorem), no quantum error correcting code capable of detecting arbitrary errors implements a universal gate set transversally (see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.4262)). Clifford group together with any non-Clifford operator is universal (see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0403025)). Therefore, if such a code implements all Clifford operators transversally then no operator outside the Clifford group can have a transversal implementation in the code.

Now, since the 7-qubit Steane code implements all Clifford operators transversally (see [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15301/transversal-logical-gate-for-stabilizer-or-at-least-steane-code), the introduction in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1382) or section 10.6.2 of Nielsen & Chuang), we conclude that no operator outside the Clifford group admits a transversal implementation in Steane code.

Thus, your list of transversal operators is already complete.