# A better name for "weakly self-dual CSS codes"

Tags: error-correction, css, self-dual

Does anyone know a better name than "weakly self-dual"/"self-orthogonal" for CSS codes where $H_X=H_Z$, for example the Steane code, and the color codes?

**Details**

In the discussion in the comments of [Example CSS codes and the properties "doubly even" and "self dual"](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26701/example-css-codes-and-the-properties-doubly-even-and-self-dual) it was pointed out that (weakly) self-duality is the property of classical codes and not quantum codes and that maybe this naming should not catch on. I agree with the sentiment after I've been corrected by my colleague :) However, he did not have any good idea around how these codes should be called.

**Classical coding terms** based on https://errorcorrectionzoo.org/c/qubit_css
and https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9608006.pdf:

A code $C$ is **self-orthogonal** or **weakly self-dual**, when $C \subseteq C^\perp$. **Dual-containing** is when $C^\perp \subseteq C$.

[Error Correction Zoo](https://errorcorrectionzoo.org/c/qubit_css) calls the $C_X=C_Z$ CSS codes "self-orthogonal" which is not much better:

[image]

To add to the confusing quality of this naming, all stabilizer codes map to classical codes over $GF(4)$ that are weakly self-dual under the symplectic product. So technically all stabilizer codes are self-orthogonal/weakly self-dual already!

Comment: Perhaps "ZX-dual"?