# How to encode one stabilizer code for $H, CX, \sqrt{Z}$ operators

Tags: stabilizer-code, clifford-group, fault-tolerance

I understood that to get fault-tolerant computing, one can start from any stabilizer group and then unitarily modifying it to get a new stabilizer group which relates to some logical operators.

For simplicity, this framework usually starts from a canonical stabilizer (which relates to an unencoded space). For example I read [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15301/transversal-logical-gate-for-stabilizer-or-at-least-steane-code) how to get a code for each of the operator $H$, $CX$ and $\sqrt{Z}$. However, this means that I am creating a different code for each operation. To perform real computing, I'd imagine an encoding operation $U$, which gives a single code and, for which, $H$, $CX$ and $\sqrt{Z}$ are simultaneously transversal logical operator.

My question is then: what is such an encoding operator $U$?